# Specifying data structure in a REST query

Tags: rest, go, get

I'm trying to write a basic REST-style query for a database in Go.  I've never worked with REST before, so I'm a bit unclear as to how deeply the principle about being able to handle any kind of data is supposed to go.  Does it violate the principle to make assumptions about the data/data types I'm getting from the database in the code for the client? Should I write the former or the latter *struct* to unpack the JSON data into?

```
type datum struct {
    ID      int16 `json:"src_id"`
    Time    int64 `json:"timestamp"`
    Lat     float64 `json:"latitude"`
    Long    float64 `json:"longitude"`
    Thermo  float64 `json:"ir_thermo_temperature_filtered"`
    Humid   float64 `json:"relative_humidity"`
    AirTemp float64 `json:"air_temp"`
    Wind    float64 `json:"wind_speed_world_filtered"`
}

type datum struct {
    ID      interface{} `json:"src_id"`
    Time    interface{} `json:"timestamp"`
    Lat     interface{} `json:"latitude"`
    Long    interface{} `json:"longitude"`
    Thermo  interface{} `json:"ir_thermo_temperature_filtered"`
    Humid   interface{} `json:"relative_humidity"`
    AirTemp interface{} `json:"air_temp"`
    Wind    interface{} `json:"wind_speed_world_filtered"`
}
```

My thinking is that maybe the latter struct violates REST principles because it makes assumptions about the data types that you'd be receiving from the server, so it isn't properly uniform.  I'm hoping I'm not correct, but I can see that conclusion could come from a strict reading of the REST principles.

Comment: It depends entirely on the API you're accessing, REST has no opinion on the matter. REST just says requests are stateless and resources are identified by URI.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are reading REST principles incorrectly.

REST is an architecture, not a protocol with strict rules. The key points are that it is stateless and that it represents the underlying resources similar to how the web operates.

REST describes resources (`datum`, in your case), how you can access and modify those resources, and how those resources should describe what other resources can be accessed relative to that resource. This is similar to how web browsing works: each page has a unique URI, and the page may contain data (fields of `datum`), and links to other pages you can reach from that page.

So in your case, the fields of `datum` is analogous to the contents of a web page. If you have other resources reachable from the `datum`, then you have to provide those as URIs to the caller, and the caller can follow them. That doesn't mean that you have to give up type safety and deal with all kinds of data. Again, this is not a protocol. If the information submitted is not in the expected format, you should return an error. Since your communication format is JSON, your data types are limited to a string, number, and boolean. You are expecting an integer for ID, and if the client sends you a string (even if it is something like "123"), it is an error. Use the first struct, if unmarshaling the input returns an error, return that to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  This may seem like a silly question, but since I was learning REST entirely on my own it was hard to know how literally to interpret some of the different provisions.